# web devices chrome and edge does not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter-web

I'm using flutter 2.0.1 stable , when i run flutter devices it show only mobile device ,but chrome and edge does not showing.
I tried to Configure the flutter tool for web support, but it did not solve a problem.
How could i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. please share the flutter doctor log summary to get accurate answer for your question.
2. Make sure there is no typo errors while running the commands,
3. once again try with flutter config --enable-web,
4. Check the browsers, simulators, IDE(VScode), flutter version are updated to the latest version.
5. Finally still facing the same problem, create new flutter project then enable web support and check for the flutter connected devices.